# Append text on a same textbox

Tags: c#

Hello I want to add the text from TextBox1 into TextBox2, after I have successfully added the text from TextBox1 into TextBox2, I want to add some more text into the TextBox2 using the same way I did. But every time I add a new text, it will just replace the old text, how can I append the new text without overwriting the old text?

Comment: Show some relevant code. Have you tried `+=` instead of `=`?

Comment: use textbox.Insert();

Comment: If it's `winforms` we can also use the method `AppendText`

Comment: @CodeCaster If you put this as an answer, I would upvote you `:)`

Comment: You can see some answers right in the comments, so I highly recommend you to delete this question, it should be deleted (your downvotes will fly away)

Comment: thanks for all the guidance, but should I delete it cause I'm afraid that others would want to refer to the answer in case anyone would need it

Comment: Although basic, I think this is a legitimate question and a problem that I, and I am sure any other coder, ran into when starting out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo code

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "whatever you add more to it.."
```

Alternatively, use a operator such as += , which does the above in the following manner:

```
TextBox2.Text += "whatever you add more to it.."
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the .Insert function like, see code example:

```
textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Insert(0, "Appended text!");
```